# R: Shift in raster reprojection

Tags: raster, r

I have a [raster](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqfps9c5ipn74pt/333105624_dgm1.xyz?dl=0) in UTM projection. The proj4 string is: `+init=epsg:25833 +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

I need to reproject the raster to DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4 (EPSG: 5678). So I did:

```
library('raster')

dtm <- read.table('333105624_dgm1.xyz', header = F, dec = '.')
dtm.raster <- rasterFromXYZ(dtm, res = c(1, 1), crs = crs('+init=epsg:25833'))
dtm.raster.rpj <- projectRaster(dtm.raster, crs = crs('+init=epsg:5678'), res = 1)
```

Unfortunatly, the reprojection doesn't align with the original:
[image]

The reprojected raster is shown above the original projected raster and as you can see it doesn't align with either the map or the original projected raster.
What do I miss here?

Comment: Can you edit your quesiton and provide a reproducible example? That is create the input and expected output `RasterLayer`s from scratch with  `raster(nrow=, ncol=   )` etc. And perhaps include a minimal version of `dtm`, or at least show some of the values (you say projection is going bad, but perhaps `dtm` is not correct?). Can you also try this with `terra` `rast(as.matrix(dtm), type="xyz")` and `project(dtm.raster)` ?

Comment: @RobertHijmans A link to the DTM in question (only about 100 mb in size) is included to the question (the word raster refers to the file). But anyway it works with the terra package. Thank you for that. It might be a workaround in my case but it doesn't deliver an answer why it doesn't work with the raster package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see a small difference between `raster` and `terra`. That is not unexpected as the extent is not exactly defined when projecting a raster based on a different CRS alone. It is better practice to provide a raster template to project to. Here is what I see:

```
options(rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings = "none")   
library(raster)
library(terra)

dtm <- read.table('333105624_dgm1.xyz', header = F, dec = '.')
dtm.raster <- rasterFromXYZ(dtm, crs = crs('+init=epsg:25833'))
dtm.raster.rpj <- projectRaster(dtm.raster, crs = crs('+init=epsg:5678'))


dtm.terra <- rast(as.matrix(dtm), type="xyz", crs ="epsg:25833")
dtm.terra.rpj <- project(dtm.terra, "epsg:5678")

plot(dtm.terra.rpj)
lines(extent(dtm.raster.rpj), col="red", lwd=4, xpd=T)
lines(ext(dtm.terra.rpj), col="blue", lwd=4, xpd=T)
```

[image]

```
e <- c(4522559, 4522565, 5624335, 5624341)
x <- crop(dtm.terra.rpj, ext(e))
y <- crop(dtm.raster.rpj, extent(e))

plot(y)
lines(as.polygons(x, dissolve=FALSE))
```

[image]